# Shouldn’t “language USE by learners” be “language USED by learners”?

Tags: grammaticality

A Cambridge english [vocabulary](https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/Images/84669-pet-vocabulary-list.pdf) says

> The Cambridge Learner Corpus is a collection of over 44 million words of English, based upon evidence of language `use` by learners from all over the world and from which the English Vocabulary Profile has developed. The English Vocabulary Profile shows the most common words and phrases that learners of English need to know in British or American English. The meaning of each word or phrase in the wordlists has been assigned a level between A1 and B2 on the CEFR.

`use` by learners in this case should be `used` by learners, is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  There are two (related) words spelled "use", the verb /ju:z/ and the noun /ju:s/.  Here the noun is being used as part of a compound noun phrase "language use"

It would also be possible to use a participle used /ju:zd/ instead of the noun, with almost the same meaning.

Comment: The pronunciation is not really relevant to the question

Comment: I think the pronunciation is relevant, @Yuri.teacher.English, becuase the verb (with /z/) wouldn't make sense, but the noun (with /s/) does.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's not true. I'm saying the pronunciation is secondary, and may be beyond the scope of what the OP asked. In fact, it could lead to confusion. For many learners of English, (e.g. native speakers of Spanish) distinguishing between /z/ and /s/ is extremely difficult. In this case, could be very unhelpful. Remember this is an ELL question. For native (or proficient) speakers of English it may seem obvious, for ELLs you're just making it much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I have done extensive research in the area of Teaching English and have read hundreds of texts on this topic.

The word use(n.) and the word use(v.) are part of the same word family. When you are talking about how people use (v.) something you can also refer to its use (n.).
Examples:

> Excessive computer use hurts your eyesight

In a similar sense, in the field of language teaching, word use is a common way to refer to how people use words.

There is a difference in pronunciation between the two words as frequently happens in English, but more important is the meaning and common use.